# Visual Studio - TFS Rollback is grouping subsequent changes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

We have a changeset that didn't make the cut and I would like to roll it back.

The problem is that we have another developer that touched the same file whose changes we would like to keep but checked in after the first changeset (2nd dev got latest w/ bad changes, added their portion then checked in). When I go to perform the rollback on the earlier changeset, it is including the subsequent changes from the later changeset in the rollback.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Why are these changesets not completely separate and how do I rollback just the changes of the earlier changeset while keeping the later changesets?

I can manually parse together the files in the merge tool but I feel like I shouldn't have to. Why isn't it just identifying the lines of the bad check-in and removing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a rollback, you can confirm the changes that result from rolling back some items match what you intend to do before you commit them to the server. As the developer modify the same file, the latter changeset will also be reset. If you change different files, the latter changeset will be reserved.

You need to do modification on the latter changset and remove the early changes.